# What are the best ways to sort out source code while scraping using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm currently learning bs4. There aren't any good resources online. I'm able to **scrape** the whole source code but how do i **scrape** down specific urls or headings using tags?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the page you're trying to scrap, and what do you want to do precisely.

Comment: http://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t=1384077 . I'm trying to scrap the sources of images (links) of the images of the forum except icons etc . All the links i need have "pzy.be" in common

Comment: This is an eerily similar question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461772/how-should-i-scrape-these-images-without-errors) which I've just answered.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
import re
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.xossip.com/showthread.php?t=1384077').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup (page, "html5lib")

img = soup.find_all("img", { "src": re.compile('^http://pzy.be') } )

for srcAttr in img:
        print srcAttr['src']
```